# Rails self-referential hierarchical relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've read Rails guides and tried a few different things w/Active Record but haven't been able to figure out what the best way to do this is.

I need to set up a self-referential (users to users) relationship that is hierarchical.  It usually would be no more than 5 levels high, but should be able to scale  up infinitely.

I've tried creating a `UserHierarchy` model with a DB schema like this:

```
parent | child | level
```

However, managing this is a bit too difficult and too complicated to handle.

What's the best way in Rails to do a self-referential hierarchical relationship?  I've checked out gems like ancestry, but the majority of them use class inheritance and don't work well for self-referential relationships.  It's a many-to-many, self-referential hierarchy (in MySQL).

Comment: What's the business use case you are trying to implement? How are users in one level related to users in another level?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need for a level; a user has nested users. The level is intrinsic to the relationship. If you search the web for self-referential relationships you should find everything you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ancestry is one of the gems that is esp. well suited for object tree structures (what you call self-referential hierarchical relationships). You should have a more detailed look at it.

Generally, there are about four common ways to store trees in a SQL database:

- *Simple parent pointers.* You just add a new column called `parent_id` to your model holding the ID of the parent object. This allows easy inserts and is well suited for single-level hierarchies but is generally difficult to use for deeper hierarchies and is thus generally not used as the primary mechanism (although it is sometimes combined with other mechanisms)
- *[Nested Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).* You define your trees as a structure of nested sets. This is typically implemented with a `right` and a `left` column which are populated with numbers to define the set. It allows efficient querying but is a bit tricky when inserting values. Esp. when having concurrent changes to a tree, it is sometimes prone to inconsistencies. This model is e.g. used to the [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) gem.
- *[Materialized Paths](https://bojanz.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/storing-hierarchical-data-materialized-path/).* This is the model e.g. used by [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). It stores the full parent path of all elements. This allows for efficient inserting and querying. Changing a tree is bit more expensive.
- *[Closure Trees](https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql).* This mechanism stores for each element all of its parents in a table. This is e.g. used by the [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem.

Generally, all these options allow to store a tree of objects, i.e. a hierarchical structure of objects of the same class (an `ActiveRecord` model in this case).

Which one to use depends on which trade-offs are more important for your specific use-case. Most importantly, you should figure out if you are changing trees often (e.g. moving sub-trees around or adding only leaves) and how you are querying the tree (e.g. do you only need direct children, do you need whole sub-trees, do you need to filter) and chose the appropriate solution based on that.